# Trouble with the legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

Have a look at the following plot:

[image]

I generated this with the following code:

```
        fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2)
        axes[0].set_title("$K = " + str(K) + " , \sigma = " + str(sigma) + "$")
        heatmap1 = axes[0].imshow(X1, interpolation='none', cmap=plt.get_cmap("seismic"))
        fig.colorbar(heatmap1)
        axes[1].set_title(r"$K = " + str(K) + ", \sigma = " + str(sigma) + "$")
        heatmap2 = axes[1].imshow(X2, interpolation='none', cmap=plt.get_cmap("seismic"))
        fig.colorbar(heatmap2)

        plt.subplots_adjust(left=None, bottom=None, right=None, top=None,
                            wspace=0.4, hspace=.4)
        plt.show()
```

However, I would like to correct the following things:

1. I want the second plot to be the same size as the first
2. The legend on the left should only appear once
3. The legend should be the same size as the y axis of both subplots

Can anybody help me with these requirements?

Comment: where is the `legend` here? Do you refer to your `title` as the legend?

Comment: With legend I mean the two bars on the right.

Comment: If you want the colorbar to appear only once, why are you calling it twice? I can see that you have two different heatmaps, then why do you want it only once? can you try `fig.colorbar(heatmap1, ax=axes[0])`

Comment: with regard to the size of your subplots, I would recommend using [GridSpec](http://matplotlib.org/api/gridspec_api.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some edits to your code, which do what you want (I think).

Rather than calling colormap twice, I have set the limits on the color scale to be the same in both plots (using `vmin` and `vmax`). Then, to get the colorbar the same height as the plots, you need to get the y-position of one of the subplots once the figure is saved, and use them to create a separate axis for the colorbar (otherwise they will steal space from, and shrink, one of your subplots).

You might need to play around with the values in `subplots_adjust` to make things fit.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X1=np.random.rand(10,10)
X2=np.random.rand(10,10)
K,sigma=10,1.5

vmin = np.minimum(X1,X2).min()
vmax = np.maximum(X1,X2).max()

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2)

axes[0].set_title("$K = " + str(K) + " , \sigma = " + str(sigma) + "$")
heatmap1 = axes[0].imshow(X1, interpolation='none',  cmap=plt.get_cmap("seismic"),
                          vmin=vmin,vmax=vmax)


axes[1].set_title(r"$K = " + str(K) + ", \sigma = " + str(sigma) + "$")
heatmap2 = axes[1].imshow(X2, interpolation='none',   cmap=plt.get_cmap("seismic"),
                          vmin=vmin,vmax=vmax)

plt.subplots_adjust(left=None, bottom=None, right=0.8, top=None,
                    wspace=0.4, hspace=.4)

fig.savefig('test.png')
cpos = [axes[0].get_position().bounds[1],
        axes[0].get_position().bounds[3]]

cax = fig.add_axes([0.9,cpos[0],0.01,cpos[1]])

fig.colorbar(heatmap1,cax=cax)

fig.savefig('test.png')
```

[image]